# asp.net MVC Form Post w/ Errors renders view with strong tags surrounding content

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm at my wits' end with this one.  In my MVC app I have simple view, layout and controller logic (returning same view w/ model) when ModelState.IsValid is false.  If the form actually submits due to it passing the unobtrusive js logic, the view is returned with <strong> tags surrounding seemingly arbitrary chunks of html.

I have chased this strong tag and can not find any reference to it in any of my views, layouts or extension code. I am not using third party libraries, this is all home grown (sans the MVC.NET part).

I realize this isn't much to go on, but I'm more looking to see if this is a known behavior and I'm just being stupid or if I made a config change somewhere that causes MVC to render with <strong> tags around chunks of html.

As an illustration this is what I'm seeing:

My source layout code looks like

```
<div id="main">

        <h2>@ViewBag.PageTitle</h2>
        @Html.Partial( "notices" )
        <div class="ajax-notice"></div>
        @RenderBody()
</div>
```

After a post is submitted and returned with errors the rendered source looks like

```
<div id="main">

    <h2>Page Title</h2>
    <div class="error">
        <strong>
            Oops! An error!
        </strong>
    </div>
    <strong>
        <div class="ajax-notice"></div>
    </strong>
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

The <strong> tag in bot the error classed div and surrounding the ajax-notice classed div are **not** in the source code.

notice Partial looks like:

```
<div class="error">@Html.ValidationSummary</div>
```

Finally I am simply returning to the same view with Controller logic like such:

```
public ActionResult Create( User model ){
    if( !ModelState.IsValid ){
        return( View ( "new", model ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your "notices" partial look like?

Comment: Added "notices" to question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here are few things to try

@Html.ValidationSummary will create a div for you with a ul tag containg all of the errors.

The output should look something like this by default:

```
<div class="validation-summary-errors">
     <ul>
           <li>Username is invalid</li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

I would first try taking the @Html.ValidationSummary out of the partialview and just render it in the regular view.  Modify your CSS to use validation-summary-errors instead of just errors as the class.

I am not sure the exact purpose for having your @Html.ValidationSummarry in a partial view anyway.